# pulling selected radio value may be giving wrong button selected?

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

I'm pulling my hair out on this one: I've got a basic radio button option, and about 2% of my users are recorded as the default option but swear up and down that they had the non-default option selected when they clicked the 'okay' button.  The 2% is the same across browsers so I don't think it's a browser-specific issue.  I'm unable to replicate the issue.

The jQuery:

```
if($("input[name=plan_selected]:checked").val() == 'unlimited')
{
    unlimitedFlag = 1;
}
else
{
    unlimitedFlag = 0;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="plan_selected" value="unlimited" checked="checked">Unlimited<br/>
<input type="radio" name="plan_selected" value="individual">Individual
```

Are my users just mistaken or is there some reason why this might not work for a small percentage of users?

Answer (score 0):

If im not mistaken I believe you should have your default checked value written like this: <input type="radio" name="plan_selected" value="unlimited" checked>Unlimited<br/>

Source: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Whether that is the only issue I am not sure but the rest of the code seems to make sense.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I will try it out and mark it correct if the 2% goes away.